# Is there a role assignment/removal event in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want my bot to listen for when a role is changed, and if it's a specific role that's changed, trigger an event for that specific user. In this case, it would be listening for the "Server booster" role and automatically assign the "Donor" role. I'd also want it to do it the other way around, so if a user loses the "Server booster" role, the "Donor" role should automatically be removed from them. Is there an event for role assignments/removals? Something like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_role_assignment(ctx, user):
    if user.role.name == "Server Booster"
        user.role.assign("Donor")
    else
        return

@bot.event
async def on_role_removal(ctx, user):
    if user.role.name == "Server Booster"
        user.role.remove("Donor")
    else
        return
```

Comment: [`on_member_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.on_member_update) though you're gonna have to code your own role assign/remove logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully created the code, figured i should post it here in case someone wants to do this as well. I should mention that you have to have the "members" intent enabled for your bot.

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    yourServer = bot.get_guild(YOUR SERVER ID)
    update_time()
    if 'Server Booster' in after.roles:
        if not 'Server Booster' in str(before.roles):
            await after.add_roles(discord.utils.get(yourServer.roles, name="Donor"))
            print(f'{current_datetime} INFO: {after.name} has boosted the server and gained the Donor Role!')
    if 'Server Booster' in str(before.roles):
        if not 'Server Booster' in str(after.roles):
            await after.remove_roles(discord.utils.get(yourServer.roles, name="Donor"))
            print(f'{current_datetime} INFO: {after.name} has stopped boosting the server and lost the Donor Role :(')
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing is

[on_member_update](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_member_update)